# How to thow and catch and timeout exception

Tags: java

I tried to catch() timeout exception, after waited for some time to see one webelement.
But java says timeout exception is never throwable.

The below method waits for any webelement for some (given) time.
Even after the time has elapsed, and could not see the web element, the Catch block will be executed.``

I want to know exactly whether this method fails due to ONLY timedout exception. So, I tried to catch it using:

```
Catch(TimeoutException te).
```

But Java says, this exception is not throwable.

```
public boolean waitForElement(final String id, String[] resultsValues)
throws  Exception {
boolean returnValue = false;
try {
returnValue = new WebDriverWait......
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Please include the code where the message is occurring and the exact wording of the message.  (And note that it's `catch`, not `Catch`.)

Comment: (And did you either `import` `java.util.concurrent.*` or fully specify `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`?)

Comment: `TimeoutException` is throwable. You can see it here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeoutException.html

Comment: None of the constructors for [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) throw a `TimeoutException`.

Comment: I believe the timeout exception is the WebDriver timeout exception http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html

Comment: Moreover you have both `throw` and `catch` at the same time. Either you `throw` it or `catch` it.

Answer (score 4):

The `WebDriverWait` `until` method is the method that throws the `TimeoutException`, not the constructor. Also, be sure you are trying to catch the WebDriver [TimeoutException](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html) , not the java.util.concurrent [TimeoutException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeoutException.html).